# how to write workflow with the help of ORM in odoo. I want ButtonType:object not workflow. I am using odoo10

Tags: odoo-10

[enter link description here](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#workflows)

how workflow write using ORM. Button type should be object not workflow.

Answer (score 0):

button type is object while name is the method. Method describe in .py file
button type is action while name is the action (%(name of action)d) and it describe in .xml file like wizard action